# Set Cron Job According to created_at And Hours given by admin in another column same table

Tags: laravel, cron

I want to set a cron job that automatically reject those bookings who are not accepted within given time by admin.

The cron job function code is

```
public function cronJob()
{
    $time = DB::table('timer')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
    $book = Booking::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subHours($time->hours))->where('accepted','=',0)->get();
    foreach($book as $row)
    {
        if($row->accepted != 1)
        {
            Booking::where('id',$row->id)->update(['rejected' => 1, 'accepted' => 0,'status' => 'Cancelled']);
        }
    }
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'Executed',
        'data' => []
    ], 201);
}
```

Currenlty i'm Using another table but i need to set time for each booking

Answer (score 1):

1. `php artisan make:job RejectUnconfirmedBooksJob`
2. check [laravel jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs)

```php
class RejectUnconfirmedBooksJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $time = DB::table('timer')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        Booking::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()
            ->subHours($time->hours))
            ->where('accepted', '=', 0)
            ->update(['rejected' => 1, 'accepted' => 0, 'status' => 'Cancelled']);
        /*
            i'm not quite sure what about $time variable and why you need it so
            i just got rid from unnecessary for loop
            BUT if you have some events in Booking model you should return loop back
         */
    }
}
```

3. in console/Kernel.php you need to define execution of the job

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->job(new RejectUnconfirmedBooksJob)
            ->everyTenMinutes() //this and below additions you can check from docs
            ->unlessBetween('19:00', '7:00')
            ->withoutOverlapping(10);
    }
```

4. next part on server (guess its some kind of linux)

open (or log in) console and enter `crontab -e` which will open cron config in vim (text editor by default). to make edits you need to press `a` and insert

```sh
* * * * * (cd /path-to-roject-folder && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

then press `Esc` and type `:qw` and `Enter`
this step adds cron to run queued jobs every minute. you can config intervals in Kernel.php (see my comment about [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs) in step 3) or in cron. but if you have several jobs with different intervals its more suitable to config it in Kernel.php for each job and leave cron as is.